# How does CNN training take place in this image?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

[image]

After watching the following great video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxfUGhug-iQ I have got a good understanding on how filters are applied, architecture of different CNN's etc.  I have watched a few other videos and read papers, but dense me still has a few questions hoping someone could help me understand this better.

We learnt different ways to slide the filter over the image.  Now, this process of getting the dot product, is this used for training the CNN or for identification with already trained filters.  Or used in both training and identification.

In the image above, were those filters trained? I understand white represents activations with the filters, but should the last column indicate anything to me?

If there are say 5 outcomes as shown in the image, **are** some of the filters (rows) specifically designed to detect certain properties of the images.  (e.g. 2nd filter looks for tyres, 3rd filter looks for headlights, 4th filter indicates hooves).  So for example the image above has tyres and headlights so those two filters are strongly mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer your questions :

1. The dot product is used both in training and identifaction phase. Computation of dot product is central operation during every usage of convolutional network - it is simply compulsory to compute the inner and final values of your net.
2. This images represents the activations of different filters after computing dot product with a set of parts of an image or outputs from previous layers. They are converted do grey-scale image and printed out to show what every filter is used for after training phase. Please notice that after every layer the resolution of an images is lower than in previous one and it's harder to understand what they might code. They simply show where each filter is activated - it's up to our interpretation what might activate them.
3. At this image you may see the **FC** layer at the end of your net. This means that after convolutional stage a computations are made in fully connected layers which are made to learn and identify certain patterns among filters which are helpful in classification stage. It's good to think about this part as an expert who is looking at what kind of filters were activated (and where) and is making decision about the class of an image.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, most helpful.  Just wanted to ask something about the 3rd point.  Your answer implies it is something akin to a black box (like ANN) where we can't really visualize the feature map as a tyre or headlight.  Is it rateable to this image https://image.slidesharecdn.com/atutorialondeeplearningaticml2013-130621020853-phpapp01/95/a-tutorial-on-deep-learning-at-icml-2013-5-638.jpg?cb=1371780897 .. here the feature maps seem to be taking shape.

Comment: As I recall - these images are created by a special technique which shows you what sort of inputs activate them the most. It's different than technique which generated images from your post. And in image you posted in your comment you also have trainable classifier which is a black box in fact.

Comment: ahh makes more sense now.  Just one final question :) How does the NN give a % of similarity for each output (Horse, car, truck).  Is the final ouput an array of all possible output with an associated 'likeliness' e.g [[horse=20%],[truck=80%],[aeroplane='10%']] etc. ty

Comment: Usually - neural network has an output for each class and the class with the biggest output is considered as a match. To have probabilities of each classes usually a softmax function is used.